# How to store messages in /mosquitto/data MQTT mosquitto?

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I am running `Docker` in `AWS ECS` and inside the docker container in ECS instance i am running `eclipse-mosquitto`

I need to store the messages in `/mosquitto/data`

**What i tried**

`docker exec -it [container name] sh` navigated to `/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`

Modified the `mosquitto.conf` file and added these lines :

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
listener 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

**NOTE**

I have mounted `EFS` on `/mosquitto` so i expect the configuration file to persist and i expect it to use that configuration file next time the container restarts

**What i expect**

Whenever i am `publishing/subscribing` to a topic it should store the relevant data under `mosquitto/data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

Logging into a running container and editing the config file won't change the running brokers behaviour.

You would normally need to restart the container (which will revert the changes to the config file)

You can mount your own config file into the container at start time with the following command line option (described on the docker hub [page](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto))

```
$ docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf eclipse-mosquitto
```

**Secondly**

mosquitto will not store all messages in the persistence file, that is not what it's for. The file is only used to store QOS 1 or 2 messages that are in flight and retained messages. These messages are normally kept in memory, but are written to the file at regular intervals or at broker shutdown so they can be restored when the broker restarts. Also the format of the persistence file is a custom binary format, it's not something you can easily read.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that i mounted `EFS`on `/mosquitto` so i expect it to retain the configuration file

Comment: I updated my question,Please can you tell me what might be going wrong ? i am new to mosquitto i started yesterday itself... Also will i have to change my default qos value to store something ?

Comment: The second part of my answer covers all that. The broker will only store retained messages or messages being delivered at QOS1 or 2 only for the time it takes to deliver them, it is NOT a way to record messages for later use.

Comment: Sure much thanks.. also i was wondering if there was any particular way i could test if mosquitto was indeed using my custom conf file instead of the default one :)